# Нужно исправить значение counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно создать класс итераторов со следующими свойствами:
Каждый объект класса должен обладать тремя атрибутами: количество элементов, шаг между
элементами, множитель. Результирующий объект является итератором, его элементы создаются
следующим образом:
Начальное значение – единица. На каждой итерации к результату предыдущей добавляется
значение шага, и эта сумма умножается на множитель. Количество итераций ограничено
количеством элементов, которое задаётся в качестве аргумента при создании экземпляра класса.

Написанный код:

```
import random
class Interators:
    def __init__(self, number, step, coeff):
        self.number = number
        self.step = step
        self.coeff = coeff

    def __iter__(self):
        self.start = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.start <= self.number:
            result = (self.start + self.step ) * self.coeff
            self.start += 1 
            return result

        else:
            raise StopIteration


test = Interators(4, 2, 0.1)
for i in test:
    print(i)
```

Нужно решить проблему следующего рода: дело в том, что 1 является пунктом отсчета, к ней добавляется шаг равный 2 и умножается на коэффициент 0.1 -> результат 0,3 . Cлед действие к 1 прибавляется 1 (из-за счетчика) и снова добавляется шаг -> результат 0,4 . А НУЖНО, чтобы к 0,3 добавился шаг и умножился на коэффициент. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это преобразовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу, то вот так:

```
class Interators:
    def __init__(self, number, step, coeff):
        self.number = number
        self.step = step
        self.coeff = coeff

    def __iter__(self):
        self.value = 1
        self.count = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count < self.number:
            result = (self.value + self.step ) * self.coeff
            self.value = result 
            self.count += 1
            return result

        else:
            raise StopIteration

test = Interators(4, 2, 0.1)

for i in test:
    print(i)
```

Результат для этих данных:

```
0.30000000000000004
0.22999999999999998
0.223
0.2223
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import random
class Interators:
    def __init__(self, number, step, coeff):
        self.number = number
        self.step = step
        self.coeff = coeff

    def __iter__(self):
        self.start = 1
        # кроме переменной индекса создаём ещё переменную результата
        self.result = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.start <= self.number:
            # раз шаг нужно прибавлять к результату - к нему и прибавляем =)
            self.result = (self.result + self.step ) * self.coeff
            self.start += 1
            return self.result

        else:
            raise StopIteration

test = Interators(4, 2, 0.1)
for i in test:
    print(i)
```

Comment: ох уж эта вечная борьба с совестью, кому поставить галочку за правильный ответ... ваш ответ тоже верный, но человек выше написал раньше, поэтому простите....а так огромное спасибо за разъяснения и хорошего дня :)

Comment: @Helloitisme не за галочками же люди на форум приходят ;) и вам хорошего дня